# What exactly is Simple Multi-Purpose Daemon?

Tags: mpi, mpich

I am just starting to learn MPI. The implementation is MPICH2. 
The first thing I encountered is SMPD i.e Simple Multi-Purpose Daemon.

I want to know what exactly it is and how it is related to MPI

Most of the [links](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ics/impi/41/lin/Reference_Manual/Multipurpose_Daemon_Commands.htm) on internet talks about its usage, but not the internal details. At max I know that:

> Multipurpose daemon* (MPD) is the Intel® MPI Library process
>   management system for starting parallel jobs.

Where can I learn more about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMPD is one implementation of parallel process manager, i.e. a system for launching/monitoring  processes in a parallel job. SMPD was specifically useful for MPI jobs on Windows or a mix of Windows and Unix. See the MPICH FAQ: http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_What_are_process_managers.3F

Also note that the newest versions of MPICH use Hydra as the default process manager, and support for Windows has been dropped.